# Join splitted -001.mkv files with bash

Tags: bash, command-line, mkv

I have some -001.mkv files splitted in this way

```
the rings + of power-001.mkv
the rings + of power-002.mkv
..

nightmare.return-001.mkv
nightmare.return-002.mkv
..
```

I need to join -001.mkv files to obtain files like this

```
the rings + of power.mkv
nightmare.return.mkv
```

I thought of such a code, but doesn't work

```
for file in "./source/*001.mkv;" \
do \
    echo mkvmerge --join \
    --clusters-in-meta-seek -o "./joined/$(basename "$file")" "$file"; \
done
```

source is the source folder where `-001.mkv` files are located
joined is the target folder

Comment: BTW, you're adding a lot of explicit line continuations that aren't actually necessary. I wonder if maybe you learned bash from examples in makefiles? One can need extra backslashes in a makefile to ensure that different lines are passed to the same shell interpreter, but that's not the case when you're writing a real/native bash script.

Comment: The immediate problem is that quoting the wildcard expression turns it into not a wildcard expression. See [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```bash
for f in ./source/*-001.mkv
do
    p=${f%-001.mkv}
    echo mkvmerge --clusters-in-meta-seek \
        -o ./joined/"${p##*/}".mkv "$p"-*.mkv
done
```

Given your example, the `for f in ./source/*-001.mkv` should loop though `nightmare.return-001.mkv` and `the rings + of power-001.mkv`.

Let's assume that we're in the first iteration and `$f` expands to `nightmare.return-001.mkv`

- `${f%-001.mkv}` right-side-strips `-001.mkv` from `$f`; that would give `./source/nightmare.return`. We store this prefix in the variable `p`.
- `${p##*/}` left-side-strips all characters up to the last `/` from `$p`; that would give `nightmare.return`.

So `... -o ./joined/"${p##*/}".mkv "$p"-*.mkv` would be equivalent to `... -o ./joined/nightmare.return.mkv ./source/nightmare.return-*.mkv`

**PS:** Once you checked that the displayed commands correspond to what you expect then you can remove the `echo`

Comment: Good answer. Might want to explain it? (Might also want to make it clear that the OP should take the `echo` off when they want to run it, and **not** pipe its output to a shell / copy-and-paste that output into a shell / etc; as the script is not currently going through the steps necessary to ensure `eval`-safe results).

Comment: @Fravadona it return me "**Error: The file '--join' could not be opened for reading: open file error.**" - please look how do I run your command [HERE](https://i.imgur.com/mOwefzk.gif)

Comment: @JackRock I never used `mkvmerge` but according to the man, this option doesn't exist (and shouldn't be needed for your purpose)